# Crontab isn't running Laravel scheduled jobs

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, cron

I've set up crontab on my AWS-EC2 instance to hit the Laravel scheduling endpoint every minute via the root account using `sudo crontab-e`:

`* * * * * php ~/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

However, despite to the cron logs showing it is indeed running every minute:

`Jan 26 12:02:01 ip-172-31-28-116 CRON[5057]: (root) CMD (php ~/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)`

the job itself isn't executing.

Running the command `php ~/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` straight up triggers the job and works.

I'm really struggling with what is going wrong here, am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like the one that works is running from a different user to the cron (root), in which case `~/` probably isn't where you're thinking it is? And since you're redirecting output, you're probably not seeing any messages.

Comment: What do you expect `~` to expand to? Try using an absolute path instead.

Comment: Fair point - I've been running both via root and user (bitnami) via `sudo crontab` and `crontab` respectively: changed the root cron job to the absolute path, but still isn't triggering the Laravel scheduler.

```Jan 26 12:19:01 ip-172-31-28-116 CRON[5245]: (root) CMD (php /home/bitnami/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)                                               
Jan 26 12:19:01 ip-172-31-28-116 CRON[5246]: (bitnami) CMD (php ~/htdocs/artisan schedule:run)```

Answer (score 2):

So, I failed to heed the cron output "No MTA installed, discarding output" - Upon installing an MTA (postfix, via `sudo apt-get install postfix`), it turned out that for the cronjob, `php` wasn't findable.

Changing the command to use the output of `which php` to:

`/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/htdocs/artisan schedule:run`

is now working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths when adding cron  entries. `~/htdocs/artisan` that should be set using the full path to your application root directory.

It works when you manually run the command because your environment is set accordingly. Not the case when adding cron entries using sudo.

Comment: Don't get triggered by a single downvote. Some people just don't get it. You are right, of course.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine it's because you're posting as an answer something that's already been suggested and tried in the comments. That's generally frowned upon.